# Won't proceed beyond login screen after upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: 14.10

Tried to reboot the computer after upgrading, before it shows the login screen, a "error while reading from descriptor broken pipe" message appears for few seconds and then proceeds to the login screen, trying to login with my main account, and it just show me a blank screen (with ubuntu background and a ubuntu 14.10 text at the bottom left corner still showing) and doesn't do anything afterwards, tried rebooting again, and tried to use a guest session, didn't work, can only access the recovery from the grub.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but after another partial upgrade with 14.10.

The solution for me was to start in safe mode, press shift key while the system loads. Then chose a safe mode, enable networking, then go to command prompt or shale.

Then reinstall the video drivers by adding a ppa and update the system with apt-get install, and reset the unity desktop with these commands:

dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

setsid unity

unity --reset-icons

then, reboot

Alternatively, you can use a live cd and connect to the root partition of your original installation by tipping: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/how-to-fix-non-bootable-ubuntu-system.html

sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
for i in /sys /proc /run /dev /dev/pts; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/
sudo chroot /mnt

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on an existing Ubuntu 14.10 installation, of a missing Unity and Dash; it also didn't respond to keystroke commands.

I reinstalled Unity, Dash and desktop functionality with the following commands:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch from the non-functioning desktop to a command line TTY. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> will bring you back to the GUI desktop.) If not, boot into a command line interface as Azaru suggests.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

The broken pipe is probably a red herring - I still have that on several machines.

Then reboot.